# I want to change the currency type of my model using globalization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, globalization

This is my model I actually want to be able to display the currency as **Rands (south African Currency)**

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]    
 public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Comment: Try this = http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/globalization-and-localization-in-Asp-Net-mvc-4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys I found a solution already..

```
 <system.web>
      <globalization culture="en-ZA" uiCulture="en-ZA" />
<system.web>
```